# MongoDB set field base on length of an array field

Tags: mongodb

Input data

```
{
user_name:"jon_doe", 
followers: ["useroneID", "usertwoID"],
followers_count: 2
}
```

my code

```
db.user.updateOne(
{user_name: "jon_doe"},
{
   $addToSet: {followers: "userthreeID"},
   $set: {followers_count: {$size: "$followers"}}
}
```

Expected output

```
{
user_name:"jon_doe", 
followers: ["useroneID", "usertwoID","userthreeID"],
followers_count: 3
}
```

Is it possible with mongoDB and how do I do it because the code above doesn't work

Comment: please add some sample input data and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Work on the [update with the aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

1. `$set` - Set `followers` field with concat arrays with `followers` and new value as an array. Work with [`$setUnion`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to prevent insertion of duplicate entries.
2. `$set` - Set `followers_count` field with get the size of `followers` array.

```
db.user.updateOne({
  user_name: "jon_doe"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      followers: {
        $setUnion: [
          "$followers",
          [
            "userthreeID"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      followers_count: {
        $size: "$followers"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vg8ju9IJkW0)

Comment: Nice, it works almost perfect, but the followers array field could have duplicates, how do I solve that.

Comment: Yes, use `$setUnion` instead of `$concatArrays`. And thanks for editing the answer.